# How can I make the Java Stanford NLP recognize a given word as a number NER?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am parsing a sentence where I want a variable "max" to be recognized as a number. I've set my file up to make SNLP recognize it as an NER of type NUMBER but it does not seem to analyze it in the same way as it does other NER NUMBER strings when they actually do represent numbers. How should I go about this?

For example:

"The method returns a number greater than max"

I am working on the above sentence. 'max' is always going to be an integer (it's a parameter for a Java method). Because of this I want SNLP to treat the word 'max' as a number for all purposes.

Comment: Could you please provide a specific example?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp I've updated my question to include specifics